# Are two matrices isomorphic? (as rings and as group)

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, group-isomorphism, ring-isomorphism

Assume that $M_2(R) , M_3(R)$ are matrices with real cells $2 \times 2$ , $3 \times 3$ respectively.
1)Are $M_2(R) , M_3(R)$ Isomorphic as rings under addition and multiplication ? why?
2) Are $M_2(R) , M_3(R)$ Isomorphic as additive groups? why?
My thoughts:
I think the part 1 can be done from some problems which already have answered in MSE. But for part 2 I don't know how to solve it I think the answer is not isomorphic but I don't know how to prove it. Could you please help me and answer that
Please help me with your hints. Thanks

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos thanks. I think the part 1 can be done from some problems which already have answered in MSE. But for part 2 I don't know how to solve it I think the answer is not isomorphic but I don't know how to prove it. Could you please help me and answer that

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos please because I have asked some questions in this site but I get never any answers and I lost my motivation.

Comment: Hi @Julia. In order to get answers, you should clearly state what motivates this question, why you are thinking that part 1 is false, from which other posts you are getting this intuition, etc. Otherwise, it just looks like you are a student who needs their homework to be done without putting any effort onto it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hints:

1. There is an element $A \in M_3(\mathbb{R})$ such that $A^3 = 0$ and $A^2 \neq 0$, but in $M_2(\mathbb{R})$ there is no such element.
2. It's equivalent to the question whether $(\mathbb{R}^4, +)$ and $(\mathbb{R}^9, +)$ are isomorphic, because clearly

   $$\mathbb{R^4} \ni \begin{pmatrix} a \\ b \\ c \\ d \end{pmatrix} \mapsto \begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix} \in M_2(\mathbb{R})$$

   is an isomorphism and likewise $M_3(\mathbb{R}) \cong \mathbb{R}^9$.

   First try to solve a simpler problem: are $(\mathbb{R}, +)$ and $(\mathbb{R}^2, +)$ isomorphic?

Comment: Thanks for your answer about rings. But for groups why that's equivalent to that question? Could you explain more? Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Julia $M_2(\mathbb{R}) \cong \mathbb{R}^4$ and $M_3(\mathbb{R}) \cong \mathbb{R}^9$ (as additive groups), so the left hand side groups are isomorphic if and only if the right hand side groups are. I added the isomorphism $M_2(\mathbb{R}) \cong \mathbb{R}^4$ to the answer.

Comment: Thank you very much I get it. I think $(\mathbb{R}^2, +),  (\mathbb{R}, +)$ are isomorphic. Because I see $\mathbb{R}^2, \mathbb{R}$ are isomorphic as a group.  Am I correct? With that how I can reach to isomorphism of $(\mathbb{R}^4, +), (\mathbb{R}^9,+)$?

Comment: @Julia You are correct and the relation $(\mathbb{R}^4, +) \cong (\mathbb{R}^9, +)$ is proved in the same way as $(\mathbb{R}^2, +) \cong (\mathbb{R}, +)$. To recal the argument: both groups can be regarded as $\mathbb{Q}$-linear spaces of dimension $2^{\aleph_0}$, so they are isomorphic as $\mathbb{Q}$-linear spaces, in particular as additive groups too.

Comment: Thank you again. But I don't understand how to do this.. what is $\aleph_0$?

Comment: Julia, google for aleph number, e.g., in wikipedia.

Comment: @Julia If you don't know what $\aleph_0$ is, then you probably have far too little background to understand why $(\mathbb{R}^4, +)$ and $(\mathbb{R}^9, +)$ are isomorphic. I recommend you familiarize yourself with the theory of set cardinalities.

Comment: @Julia However, it's relatively easy to prove that $(\mathbb{R}^4, +) \cong (\mathbb{R}^9, +)$ **given that** $(\mathbb{R}, +) \cong (\mathbb{R}^2, +)$. Here's how: $$\mathbb{R}^4 \cong \big( \mathbb{R}^2 \big)^4 = \mathbb{R}^8 = \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}^7 \cong \mathbb{R}^2 \times \mathbb{R}^7 = \mathbb{R}^9$$